# C factorial Table (1!-5!) Using For Loop

Tags: c, for-loop, factorial

This my first post on here. I'd like to ask about a problem that I am trying to do for homework.

I'm supposed to be constructing a for loop for the "first 5 factorials" and display results as a table. I followed an example in the book, and I have my for loop and my operations set up, but I don't know what to do to produce the loop in the table. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    //Problem: Display a range for a table from n and n^2, for integers ranging from 1-10.

   int n, factorialnumber, i;

    printf("TABLE OF FACTORIALS\n");
    printf("n        n!\n");
    printf("---     -----\n");

   for (n = 1; n <= 10; n++) {
        factorialnumber = factorialnumber * n;

        printf("\n %i = %i", factorialnumber, n);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

I know the printf here is wrong. What would I type?
BTW, I'm using codeblocks.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the `printf`? What does it print, and what should it print instead?

Comment: `factorialnumber` isn't initialize.

Comment: You should think by yourself. BTW, take the habit of compiling with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: Try setting factorialnumber to one. (i.e `int factorialnumber = 1`) as Bluepixy points out.  Also,  I would change the order of factorialnumber and n in your printf statement.  It seems to make more sense to write "5! = 125" instead of "125 = 5!"....but that is just me.

Comment: I literally don't understand enough to get it to print what I want. I'm lookng for it to print the results for a table (columns n and n! for factorials) and I don't understand printf all that well necessarily. I think I'm correct with the loop,I just don't know how to print and represent it.

The columns print ( __n__, and __n!__,) just not the values for it. I'd like to do that and understand how.  I get learning on my own and Socratic method but I just figured I'd get a little help.

Comment: EDIT: Got it. Thanks for the suggestion, I hate being such a noob / a "vampire" for help, but I really am that new and I really don't know what I'm doing. I guess my real question would be "how would I gain an understanding of how to display things in printf".

Comment: @TaylorBee Look up "C Primer Plus" by Steve Prata. Great introductory C text. Will make your life easier. I think PDFs are even legitimately available for free, last I checked.

Comment: @Bluepixy ...DOH!  I know what 5! is ... I plead wife distraction while I type :).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you didn't initialize the variables (e.g. `factorialnumber`). If it has an initial value of 6984857 let's say,  the whole algorithm would be messed up.

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    //Problem: Display a range for a table from n and n^2, for integers ranging from 1-10.

    int i, factorialnumber = 1;
    int n = 10;  // Max number to go through

    printf("TABLE OF FACTORIALS\n");
    printf("i        i!\n");
    printf("---     -----\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        factorialnumber *= i;
        printf("%d!  =  %d\n", i, factorialnumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```